# How add elements (key =>value) to an empty array?

Tags: php

How add elements (key =>value) to an empty array with a loop? To build Json data for AJAX response.
I've tried array_push. But not works

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $row) { 
   array_push($arr, $row->key => $row->value);                          
}   
$data['message'] = json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Do you know the syntax for accessing array members within foreach?

Comment: correct this $arr = array();..

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+add+elements+array will return more relevant results than this post ever will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($result as $row) { 
   $arr[$row->key] = $row->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is tested code.

```
$arr = array();

$result = array
(
    'one' => 'One',
    'two' => 'Two',
    'three' => 'Three',
);

foreach ($result as $key => $value)
{
   array_push($arr, array($key => $value));                          
}   
$data['message'] = json_encode($arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

**Result would be**

```
Array
(
    [message] => [{"one":"One"},{"two":"Two"},{"three":"Three"}]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` sign is overloaded in php:

```
$arr += $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple

Let you have array

```
$name = array("a,b,c,d");
```

Now if you want to convert it into key=>value then simply use

```
$name = array_values($name);
```

You are done. Just check it by printing it using

```
print_r($name);
```